# Turborepo: Unable to resolve "expo" from "index.ts"

Tags: react-native, expo, pnpm, turborepo

I'm trying to run expo on a turborepo.

Running `pnpm dev` gives me the following error:

```bash
Unable to resolve "expo" from "index.ts"
```

And the simulator the [following screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5l8Z.png) with the following error:

```bash
Unable to resolve module expo from /Users/xx/main/apps/expo/index.ts: expo could not be found within the project or in these directories:
  node_modules
  ../../node_modules
> 1 | import { registerRootComponent } from "expo";
    |                                        ^
  2 |
  3 | import { App } from "./src/_app";
  4 |
```

I have tried to delete all my `node_modules`.
I have tried to clean my entire project.
I have no idea what to do next.

Here is my `metro.config.js`:

```js
// Learn more: https://docs.expo.dev/guides/monorepos/
const { getDefaultConfig } = require("expo/metro-config");
const path = require("path");

const projectRoot = __dirname;
const workspaceRoot = path.resolve(projectRoot, "../..");

// Create the default Metro config
const config = getDefaultConfig(projectRoot);

// Add the additional `cjs` extension to the resolver
config.resolver.sourceExts.push("cjs");

// 1. Watch all files within the monorepo
config.watchFolders = [workspaceRoot];
// 2. Let Metro know where to resolve packages and in what order
config.resolver.nodeModulesPaths = [
  path.resolve(projectRoot, "node_modules"),
  path.resolve(workspaceRoot, "node_modules"),
];
// 3. Force Metro to resolve (sub)dependencies only from the `nodeModulesPaths`
config.resolver.disableHierarchicalLookup = true;

module.exports = config;
```

Here is my `package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "@acme/expo",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "main": "index.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "rm -rf .expo .turbo node_modules",
    "dev": "expo start --ios",
    "dev:android": "expo start --android",
    "dev:ios": "expo start --ios",
    "lint": "eslint",
    "type-check": "tsc --noEmit"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "~47.0.12",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.2",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-dom": "18.1.0",
    "react-native": "0.70.5",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.4.1",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.17.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.19.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.19.3",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.19.0",
    "@expo/config-plugins": "^5.0.4",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.25",
    "@types/react-native": "~0.70.8",
    "eslint": "^8.30.0",
    "typescript": "^4.9.4"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Thanks you for helping.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get it working with pnpm (I tried for way too long), so I switched over to yarn 1 (classic) workspaces and it worked. Yarn 1 workspaces are the only workspace solution that Expo supports, so I recommend going with that.

Comment: It’s actually working to go on with yarn. Sadly couldn’t make it work with pnpm

Answer (score 0):

1. I thinks you should try changing the extension of file to .tsx instead of .ts if you are rendring anything
2. If not then you should try removing node_modules and install it again and then reload vs code or any editor you are using